# Grouped products with no associated products - code not working

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

I'm trying to get a list of all grouped products with no associated products.

I have the following code but it is not showing anything.

I know there is a least one grouped product with no associated products because I created a test one.

```
require_once '*<path-to>*/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
    $NoAssociatedProducts = count($associatedProducts);
    if ($NoAssociatedProducts <1){
    $grouped_name = $product->getName();
    echo $grouped_name;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the below filter in the product collection

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

The name attribute of the products doesn't come with the below line of code.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection();
```

Instead you have too call explicitly to load that attributes to the collection shown as below.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

So finally the corrected code will be as follows.

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php'; // Put your Mage.php path here
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // Added only this line to get all attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
    $NoAssociatedProducts = count($associatedProducts);
    if ($NoAssociatedProducts < 1) {
        $grouped_name = $product->getName();
        echo $grouped_name;
    }
}
```